# Problem running Celery task inside Docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, celery

### What I have

I have a container with Django app that executes a Celery task whose purpose is to delete some files that are the `media` folder, that container is called `backend` in `docker-compose.yml`.

### Problem

the problem is that the `Celery Worker` and `Celery beat` container runs normally and execute the task but does not delete `media` files. it may be that the problem lies in the `volumes` mounted on the containers and somehow Celery does not find the media files to be deleted.

### docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  # Django app that will upload the files from the admin and that will be deleted by the Celery task.
  backend:
    expose:
      - 8000
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    networks:
      - backend-tier
    depends_on:
      - db

  redis:
    image: library/redis:5.0-alpine
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - backend-tier
    volumes:
      - valor-redis:/data

  worker:
      build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
      command: celery -A config --app=config.celery_app:app worker --loglevel=info
      restart: unless-stopped
      networks:
        - backend-tier
      depends_on:
        - redis
      volumes:
        - ./app_com_co/:/app/app_com_co:Z,cached
        - ./app_com_co/templates/:/app/app_com_co/templates:Z,cached
        # shared volume between worker and backend for media
        - app-media:/app/app_com_co/media
  
  beat:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    command: celery -A config --app=config.celery_app:app beat --loglevel=info
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - backend-tier
    depends_on:
      - redis
    volumes:
      - ./app_com_co/:/app/app_com_co:Z,cached
      - ./app_com_co/templates/:/app/app_com_co/templates:Z,cached
      # shared volume between beat and backend for media
      - app-media:/app/app_com_co/media

volumes:
  app-redis:
    driver: local
  app-media:

networks:
  backend-tier:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: how do those media files should get there in the first place? uploaded from `backend` container?

Comment: @ItayB  Yes, its uploaded from backend container (from the Django admin)... . The Celery task will check every day and find the files that are at a certain date and delete them.

Comment: so why didn't you add the `app-media` volume to the `backend` container as well?

Comment: you're right, the `app-media` volume needed to be added to `backend` to delete the files. one additional question, what kind of volume to apply a `named shared volume` or a `Host volume` fit better for this case.

Comment: not sure what you are asking, can you elaborate? and I added my answer, if it solves your question please accept that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the `app-media` volume that needed to be added to `backend` if the files are uploaded there.